# Qt QList not working as expected

Tags: c++, qt, qlist

I am building a `QList<QList<double>> *` the following way, to be returned in function `randomPoint()`:

```
QList<QList<double>> *solverMethod::randomPoint(double* bottom_, double* top_, int items_)
{  
    QList<QList<double>> *lstPt_ = new QList<QList<double>>;

         for(int i=0;i<items_;i++)
        {   
            QList<double>  pt_;
            lstPt_->append(pt_);
            for(int j=0;j<m_ndim;j++)
            {
                pt_.append(TRandom::rand(bottom_[j],top_[j]));
            }
         }
        return lstPt_;
 }
```

But with a stopping point after for loop, I notice that `pt_` is filled in properly (`m_ndim` elements), whereas `lstPt` is made of `item_` empty `QList<double>`. What is happening?

Comment: What is pt_ in the first loop? Something is missing or wrong in the code copied.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
lstPt_->append(pt_);
```

This puts a *copy* of `pt_` in the outer list. You then populate the local `pt_`, leaving the copy empty. You should move this line after the loop that fills `pt_`. Specifically:

```
QList<double>  pt_;
for(int j=0;j<m_ndim;j++)
{
    pt_.append(TRandom::rand(bottom_[j],top_[j]));
}
lstPt_->append(pt_);
```

Comment: @dlib: Then I suggest you try again; I'm fairly sure that changing the code to match my answer will change the result.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
QList<double>  pt_;
for(int j=0;j<m_ndim;j++)
{
    pt_.append(TRandom::rand(bottom_[j],top_[j]));
}
lstPt_->append(pt_);
```

When you do this:

```
lstPt_->append(pt_);
```

a copy of pt_ is added to lstPt_ (the copy constructor of QList will be invoked). So if pt_ is empty when you add it to lstPt_, then an empty list will be added.
An alternative would be to use:

```
QList< QList<double>* > lstPt_;
...
QList<double>*  pt_ = new QList<double>;
lstPt_->append(pt_);
for(...)
{
    ...
}
```

In this case you don't have this problem, but you have to clean up (delete) every single instance of pt_ you create.

Gerald